# How to classify image using custom model in tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

The script that builds and trains the model looks like this:

```
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
  inputShape: [160, 200, 3],
  filters: 32,
  kernelSize: 3,
  activation: 'relu',
}));

model.add(tf.layers.flatten());

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: labels.length, activation: 'softmax'}));  

model.compile({
  optimizer: 'sgd',
  loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
  metrics: ['accuracy']
});    

const info = await model.fitDataset(ds, {epochs: 5});
console.log('Accuracy:', info.history.acc);

console.log('Saving...');
await model.save('file://' + MODEL_PATH);
console.log('Saved model');
```

`ds` consists of images and labels. For 100 images I get these results:

`4478ms 135692us/step - acc=0.109 loss=14.37`

and it produced a 20 MB weights.bin file...

Frankly, I have no idea if that's good or not because I don't know how to use it classify new images.

I know how to load the model:

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://' + MODEL_PATH + '/model.json');
```

but that's it.

mobilenet has a `.classify` method to which I can just pass an image and it outputs the predicted laabel. But this is not available on the model object.. So how do I proceeed?

Answer (score 1):

After training your model, to classify a new image, the `predict` method will be used. It will return the probability of each label given your input image(s).

```
output = model.predict(image) // It can be a tensor of one image or a batch of many 
// output is a tensor that contain the probability for each label
images.argMax([-1]) // contain the label of high probability for each input
```

Comment: I get this error: Error when checking : expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [100,200,3]

Comment: It is because your image is a tensor3d. You will need to do `image_reshaped = tf.expandDims(image)` and predict from the reshaped image

Comment: thanks. the result I get is a label tensor, but it doesn't match at all with the corresponding label. And I provided an image that I used in training

Comment: It is not because the image was used during the training that the model will predict its label correctly. Some predictions will be correct whereas other might be wrong. It is related to the accuracy of the model

Comment: ah ok. do you know if I can also get the probability percentage, like in mobilenet.classify() ?

Comment: `model.predict(image)` return the probability. Try to print the tensor output and you will see the probability for each label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204698/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-alex).

Comment: @Alex, you need to add  `activation: 'softmax'` on the last layer